# Search with 'LIKE' function within an inner join

Tags: sql, join, sql-like

I know the following statement is invalid:

```
SELECT Terms.LName, Terms.FName, AS400.SystemID, AS400.userid, AS400.Status, AS400.text
FROM Terms 
    INNER JOIN AS400 ON WHERE text LIKE %Terms.LNAME = AS400.text;
```

The `AS400.text` field is a free text field on the AS400 that we use to store users first and last name.

What I would like to do is search the AS400.text field for the contents of the `Terms.LName` field.

I did create a dummy `AS400.LName` column to test my inner join, and this works fine:

```
SELECT Terms.LName, Terms.FName, AS400.SystemID, AS400.userid, AS400.Status, AS400.text
FROM Terms 
    INNER JOIN AS400 ON Terms.LName = AS400.LName;
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
SELECT 
 Terms.LName,
 Terms.FName, 
 AS400.SystemID, 
 AS400.userid, 
 AS400.Status, 
 AS400.text
FROM 
 Terms 
 INNER JOIN AS400 ON 
   AS400.text LIKE '%' + Terms.LNAME + '%'
```

Comment: Had to tweak it a bit, I think this will get it.              SELECT 
 AS400.text,
 AS400.userid
FROM 
 Terms 
 INNER JOIN AS400 ON 
   AS400.text LIKE (CONCAT ('%',Terms.LNAME) || '  ' || CONCAT (Terms.FNAME, '%'));